# Angular 4 App in Apache Server

Tags: apache, angular, .htaccess

I would like an htaccess file example to use in my Apache server.

The scenario is as follows:

I have an Angular 4 app that needs to run separate from back-end server. I deploy the front using the ng build command (for some internal problems I do not use ng build --prod) and put the generated files in the htdocs/app folder.

For client specific needs, I have to use relative urls for apache to redirect.

Ex: The url that would be http://www.app.com/app/something, should be api/app/something.

I already searched Google and Stackoverflow, and none of the suggested solutions worked. My htacces looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule "api/app" "http://localhost:8080/app/rest/v1$1" [P]

RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^. * $ - [NC, L]

RewriteRule ^ (. *) Index.html [NC, L]
```

The idea is that when I make a request on my angular server, it sees the api/app path and redirects to localhost. I already have this proxy working on dev via angular-cli, but I need to use this in apache too.

Another thing is that when I use my routes without the hash ("#"), the app not reloads. If I start from root ('/') it follows the route correctly, but when I refresh the page I get 404 error.

I hope I was clear on my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put the folwoing code in main directory .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+api/app/ [NC]

 #above line will exclude any api/app/something request from the folwoing rule

 RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ api/app/$1 [R=302,L,NE]

 #above line will change any app/something request to api/app/something

 RewriteRule ^api/app/(.*)$ app/$1 [L,NC]

 #the last line will direct the request api/app/something to the correct path /app/something
```

### Update

Regarding your comment , I prefer to answer here because someone else will benefit  from this answer .
you are looking to change app/something to api/app/something and you can't control that from app itself , because the host will consider app as sub folder to api , when the request coming like api/app/ it will search api folder unless there is rule in main directory to guide it other location .

if you want to change it from app to app/api is different issue and you could do it from app folder because the host will apply the rule in app to its sub folders .

So, in your case , i could give you code to redirect any app to api/app from app folder but it will not be able to override folder api unless you put this rule in main directory .

The code that i wrote for you is to redirect any request app to api/app/ but if there is api folder and have also app folder it will overide it and go to app folder otherwise any api request without app will go to api folder .

If you have api folder and want to override it or want to redirect any api/ request to app , ad the following line at the end to the code above and put all code in main directory .htaccess  and any api/ or api/app will be handeled as app/ request

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ a/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: The main directory that you say is the folder inside the htdocs folder? My .htaccess is located at C:\Apache24\htdocs\app. I'm using Windows 7.